# Mongoose custom attribute name mapping

Tags: mongoose, mean-stack

I have a collection with an 'options' attribute but it is a reserved word in Mongoose.
I don't want to change my entire collection in MongoDB to avoid this issue, so I was wondering if it is possible to customize the mapping when defining a new Schema in Mongoose.

This is my current Schema

```
var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
  question: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  answer: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  options: [String]
});
```

Maybe i can use `ops` in Mongoose but `options` in MongoDB

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem with having an options property. I ended up just going with opts in my database. If you reeeally don't want to do that you could look at mongoose built in [virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals). As an alternative [this](https://github.com/ramiel/mongoose-aliasfield) library does what you want.